# NET C# Console application not detecting key presses correctly

Tags: c#, windows, console, console-application

I have a console program. Its purpose is to check if the keys F1-F2 is pressed in a loop and then send out a message if one of those keys is pressed but I cannot get it to work properly. The way I detect or listen for keys is `if(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F2)`. `Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F2` Blocks the execution and waits for input so I have to put `Console.KeyAvailable` in front of it, so the loop can just continue and check if the next key is pressed. I did this in a `while(true)` loop, in `Main()` until I reached out to one of my friends who told me to put the whole thing in a standalone thread. I did just that which made almost no difference (besides some cleaner code).

I read about `Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key)` method, but turns out this doesn't work in a C# NET Console app. Currently, the loop doesn't even want to go past checking if F1 is pressed unless I make another separate thread to check if F2 is pressed, which results in it still not working and having to spam the keys to get the `if`s to do anything in the first place.

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread ThreadObj = new Thread(F1); //Creating the Thread    
            ThreadObj.Start(); //Starting the Thread    

        }
        static void F1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread Started");
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("F1");
                }
                if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("F2");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why do you need threads here.

1. Run the while loop and check if there is [KeyAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_KeyAvailable). Only if the key is available (a user pressed something), use the ReadKey function that blocks the thread.
2. Provide a key that breaks the loop (ESC in this case).

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to quit.");

        ConsoleKey key;
        do
        {
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                // Do something
            }

            key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if(key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.F12 || key == ConsoleKey.F11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F12 or F11 pressed");
            }

        } while (true);
    }
   ```

Comment: That's smart! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

A key point to understand is that `ReadKey()` consumes the keypress.  So after checking for F1 in the first `if` statement, the `KeyAvailable()` call in the second `if` statement will return `false` and therefore you'll never detect anything but F1.

You want to wait until there is a key available, and then call `ReadKey()` ONCE, using that same return value in multiple checks:

```
        while (true)
        {

            // wait for a keypress
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true); // call ReadKey() once...

            // ...and use "cki" multiple times
            // (note there are no more ReadKey() calls below)
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F1");
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F2");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

using System.Threading;

class Program

{

    public static void Main()

    {
        Thread ThreadObj = new Thread(F1); //Creating the Thread    
        ThreadObj.Start(); //Starting the Thread

    }
    static void F1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread Started");
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F1");
            }
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F2");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadKey consumes the key, so your submission misbehaves, and thus fails to answer the question.